# Is it possible to install two or more modules at the same time in python(installing statsmodels)

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have to install `blosc` and `statsmodels` due to findatapy. but `blosc` is blaming `statsmodels` in the installation and `statsmodels` is on the other hand, blaming `blosc` for not installing. Is it possible to install these two modules at the same time?

Comment: How does one module "blame" another? Please give a [mcve] and say what the error message is.

Comment: Are these version checks? Please explain!

Comment: it says "Failed building blosc" and "statsmodels"are not installed in red  during installation

Comment: do you have installed Microsoft C++ build tools 14.0 or plus in your system? if you are using windows.....

Comment: Okay, that text would be good to post. Apparantly blosc has a build step that is failing, we need to figure out why.

Comment: @ Nihal  Yes I am. And I also used "CMake" for building blosc, but no avail...

Comment: It would help if you describe the exact steps that you are doing. Giving a [mcve] will better allow others to help you.

Comment: @HannahLee you need to install [microsoft build tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) first

Comment: @ John Coleman, At First I tried installing "finadatpy" using pip install git+https://github.com/cuemacro/findatapy.git  But then, I found out "statsmodels" was not insatlled. So I tried to install it along with other dependencies..But "blosc" was not successful, because it required "statsmodels"

Comment: On my Mac I have no issue installing the findatapy module in a clean python 2.7 or python 3.6 virtualenv. But as John suggested, please update your post with an actual example of the commands you are running in your shell and what output they give.